# Manifest Tool can't always write to DLL or EXE

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build

Since upgrading to VS 2010 (from 2005), we've sporadically seen warnings like this:

```
Warning: mt.exe failed to write to <our DLL>; retrying.
```

Often mt retries once and succeeds.  Occasionally it tries four times and then fails.  It appears to be a timing problem.

Our first theory was that our anti-virus (which scans on access) was momentarily locking the DLL to scan it and that sometimes that would take longer than mt cared to wait.  But the problem persists even if we disable the anti-virus.

Has anyone else seen this problem and successfully diagnosed it?

Comment: Yes, this is very strongly associated with anti-virus programs.  They get really exited when an executable appears from nowhere.  Still having this problem after disabling it makes it a vexing problem.  Use taskmgr.exe, Processes tab to kill executables.  Or SysInternals' ProcMon tool to see who else is interested in that file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Hans Passant's suggestion of trying [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), I discovered that there's nannyware scanning executables as the linker creates them.

In our case, it's [Bit9](http://www.bit9.com/) (parity.exe). There's a race condition between Bit9 trying to scan the binary after the linker creates it and the manifest tool trying to update it.

This is similar to what happens when you have anti-virus software that actively scans new files, but since we had disabled our anti-virus the problem was puzzling.

Comment: Know what runs on your machine.  Everything.

Comment: Bit9 was a recent push by our IT department.